# Marshalling LocalDate using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm building a series of linked classes whose instances I want to be able to marshall to XML so I can save them to a file and read them in again later.

At present I'm using the following code as a test case:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class LocalDateExample
{
  @XmlRootElement
  private static class WrapperTest {
    public LocalDate startDate;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException
  {
    WrapperTest wt = new WrapperTest();
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2016, 3, 1);
    wt.startDate = ld;
    marshall(wt);
  }

  public static void marshall(Object jaxbObject) throws JAXBException
  {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbObject.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(jaxbObject, System.out);
  }
}
```

The XML output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wrapperTest>
    <startDate/>
</wrapperTest>
```

Is there a reason why the `startDate` element is empty? I would like it to contain the string representation of the date (i.e. `toString()`). Do I need to write some code of my own in order to do this?

The output of `java -version` is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You will have to create an `XmlAdapter` like this:

```
public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return LocalDate.parse(v);
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

And annotate your field using

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
```

See also `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters` if you want to define your adapters on a package level.

Comment: Well maintained existing implementation might be considered https://github.com/threeten-jaxb/threeten-jaxb .

Answer (score 11):

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html describes the hole setup.

> Joda-Time provides an alternative to the Date and Calendar classes currently provided in Java SE.  Since they are provided in a separate library JAXB does not provide a default mapping for these classes.

To register the adapter for all files in a package. you can add package-info.java in the package you want to register it.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class, 
        value=LocalDateAdapter.class),
})
package PACKAGE_NAME;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

The adapter looks like:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate>{

    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return LocalDate.parse(v);
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
        return v.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not using Joda Time, I'm using the `java.time.*` classes (which seem to be similar but are part of Java 8 and therefore don't need to be specified as a dependency).

Comment: You're right. I was just using an old solution of mine to test yours. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

As [*Nikolay Antipov* mentioned in this commment](https://github.com/threeten-jaxb/threeten-jaxb) there is already a well-tested **`threeten` library** that [provides 14 type adapters](https://threeten-jaxb.github.io/threeten-jaxb-core/javadoc/io.github.threetenjaxb.core/io/github/threetenjaxb/core/package-summary.html) (as of 2021-04-26) where one of them is the:

[*LocalDateXmlAdapter*](https://threeten-jaxb.github.io/threeten-jaxb-core/javadoc/io.github.threetenjaxb.core/io/github/threetenjaxb/core/LocalDateXmlAdapter.html)

and can be used e.g. like this on some Java field (generally not recommended by me though):

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateXmlAdapter.class) myLocalDt;
```

Instead I would **recommend the *`package-info.java`* approach** to do it implicitly in each package on the package level so it is applied automagically to e.g. all fields of the `LocalDate` type in all package classes:

- create a file named `src/java/my/xmlconv/classes/package-info.java`
- its content:

  ```
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter.class, type=LocalDateTime.class)
  })
  package my.xmlconv.classes;

  import java.time.LocalDateTime;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
  import io.github.threetenjaxb.core.LocalDateTimeXmlAdapter;
  ```