# No default constructor found on class java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, xml, loading, marshalling, unmarshalling

So I have the classes `Driver`, `Database`, `LogBookEntry` and `Car`. As the classes have a lot of setters and getters, I decided to put the code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com):

- [LogBookEntry](https://pastebin.com/Fxr3Ej0D)
- [Driver](https://pastebin.com/YVtGTX00)
- [Database](https://pastebin.com/BjDwYX9k)
- [Car](https://pastebin.com/AQgXRK63)

So as you can see in database I have 2 functions to load and save XML data.

Here is my output of saved XML data:

[image]

As you can see the date of the class `LogBookEntry` won't be saved into the XML File. That is the reason why I get the following error when loading the xml file:

> Okt 22, 2017 3:36:33 PM com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ClassFactory
>   create0 INFORMATION: No default constructor found on class
>   java.time.LocalDate java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   java.time.LocalDate.()

But I don't understand why the date of the `LogBookEntry` class won't be saved. The three `LocalDate` variables in the class `driver` being are saved.

Comment: Create a `XmlAdapter`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156741/marshalling-localdate-using-jaxb

Comment: @davidxxx But why don't I need a XmlAdapter when I only want to save the driver without the logbookentry class? If I only save the driver without the logbookentry the localdate will be saved without an XmlAdapter

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the return value of 'getDate' in class 'LogBookEntry' to `String` and adding the `XmlRootElement` annotation  to the class 'Car' will fix the problem