# Making SimpleDateFormat thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, simpledateformat

I have many threads processing `Trade` objects where I use a `RowMapper` to map database columns to `Trade` object.

I understand `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe in any Java. As a result, I get some unpredictable result in `startDate`. For example, I see date which is `endDate` also in `startDate`.

Here is my code:

```
public class ExampleTradeMapper {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

    public void map(Trade trade, ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {    

        trade.setStartDate(getFormattedDate(rs.getDate("START_DATE")));
        trade.setEndDate(getFormattedDate(rs.getDate("END_DATE")));
        trade.setDescription(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION"));

    }

    private String getFormattedDate(Date date) {
        try {
            if (date != null)
                return DATE_FORMAT.format(date).toUpperCase();
            else
                return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}


public class SomeRowMapper extends TradeMapper implements RowMapper<Trade> {

    @Override
    public Trade mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Trade trade = new Trade();

        map(trade, rs, rowNum);

        return trade;
    }
}
```

My core pool size is about 20 for this application with maximum about 50. These threads can be processing about 100s of trade records from the database at some time.

What would be the best way to make this date formatting thread safe? Should I be using a direct replacement using [FastDateFormat](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html)?

Is there a better alternative way of doing making this thread safe?

Comment: You could try instantiating `SimpleDateFormat` local to when you actually need the formatting.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840803/why-is-javas-simpledateformat-not-thread-safe you can choose to use DateTimeFormatter, or a single instance of SDF per thread.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTomeFormatter`. Which BTW is thread-safe.

Comment: If `Trade` is your model class, why are your keeping dates as strings in it? General recommendation is to keep date objects, preferably `LocalDate` objects. Doing so would only move your problem to when you are presenting your data to the user, of course, but I found it worth asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

Rather than using strings, use *java.time* objects (`LocalDate` specifically) exchanged with your database via JDBC 4.2 or later.

```
myResultSet.getObject(      // Exchange modern java.time objects with your database.
    "START_DATE" ,
    LocalDate.class 
)                           // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.format(                    // Generate a `String` representing textually the content of this `LocalDate`. 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MMM-uuuu" , Locale.US )
)
```

> 23-Jan-2018

Being immutable objects, the *java.time* objects are thread-safe by design. You can cache the *java.time* objects for use across threads.

## *java.time*

> Making SimpleDateFormat thread safe

Don’t.

Use the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, and `Calendar`.

The *java.time* classes are designed to be thread-safe. They use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern, to return fresh objects based on the values of an original rather than “mutating” (altering) the original.

## Use smart objects, not dumb strings

I see no reason for using strings in your example code: Not in your database access code, not in your business object (`Trade`).

### JDBC

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. For a database column of a type akin to the SQL-standard `DATE`, use the class `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate myLocalDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

### Business object

Your `Trade` class should be holding member variables `startDate` & `endDate` as `LocalDate` objects, not strings.

```
public class Trade {
    private LocalDate startDate ;
    private LocalDate endDate ;
    … 

    // Getters
    public LocalDate getStartDate() { 
        return this.startDate ;
    }
    public LocalDate getEndDate() { 
        return this.endDate;
    }
    public Period getPeriod() {  // Number of years-months-days elapsed.
        return Period.between( this.startDate , this.endDate ) ;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setStartDate( LocalDate startDateArg ) { 
        this.startDate = startDateArg ;
    }
    public void setEndDate( LocalDate endDateArg ) { 
        this.endDate = endDateArg ;
    }

    @Override
    public toString() {
        "Trade={ " + "startDate=" + this.startDate.toString() …
    }
…
}
```

No need for strings, no need for formatting patterns.

## Strings

To exchange or store date-time values as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than a custom format as seen in your Question.

The *java.time* classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ; // January 23, 2018.
String s = ld.toString() ;  // Outputs 2018-01-23.
```

For presentation in a user-interface, let *java.time* automatically localize. To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.FULL )
                     .withLocale( l ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

> mardi 23 janvier 2018

The `DateTimeFormatter` class is thread-safe, by design, as an immutable object. You could hold one instance to be used across threads.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the very useful explanation :). Since my `Trade` business object is of XML schema type annotated with `@XmlType`, the date fields must have format `dd-MMM-yyyy` in uppercase. Should I still have `Localdate` type in business object ?

Comment: I find it best to “tell the truth” in my programming. So yes, I’d keep a date-only value as a `LocalDate` type. Then bolt on whatever extra you need to make your XML framework happy. What XML framework are you using? Check to see if it has been updated to support java.time types. If not, can you tag a *getter* method returning that string as your XML property? And edit your Question to include these relevant facts.

Comment: maybe write an adapter class `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class)` and return formatted date in `marshall()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156741/marshalling-localdate-using-jaxb

Answer (score 3):

You can make it [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). Every thread in the pool will hold their own formattor.

```
private static final ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> DATE_FORMAT = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {
    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    }
};
```

Comment: be aware of memory leaks when using thread locals and not cleaning them

Comment: @white *My core pool size is about 20 for this application with maximum about 50*...  I think it will not cause memory leak.

Comment: it is not only about SDF instances, you keep a link on entire classloader, https://plumbr.io/blog/locked-threads/how-to-shoot-yourself-in-foot-with-threadlocals f.ex.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the fastest way to use date format in thread safe way. Because you have 3 ways to do it :

1. With `DateFormat.getDateInstance()`
2. With `synchronized`
3. And the local thread way which from far offers the best performance

Full code sample :

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleDateFormatThreadExample {

    private static String FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss";

    private static SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String dateStr = "02-1-2018 06:07:59";

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                parseDate(dateStr);
            }

        };

        Runnable taskInThread = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ConcurrentDateFormatAccess concurrentDateFormatAccess = new ConcurrentDateFormatAccess();
                    System.out.println("Successfully Parsed Date " + concurrentDateFormatAccess.convertStringToDate(dateStr));
                    // don't forget to use CLEAN because the classloader with keep date format !
                    concurrentDateFormatAccess.clean();
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executorService.submit(task);
            // remove this comment to use thread safe way !
            // executorService.submit(taskInThread);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    private static void parseDate(String dateStr) {
        try {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
            System.out.println("Successfully Parsed Date " + date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println("ParseError " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static class ConcurrentDateFormatAccess {

        private ThreadLocal<DateFormat> df = new ThreadLocal<DateFormat>() {

            @Override
            public DateFormat get() {
                return super.get();
            }

            @Override
            protected DateFormat initialValue() {
                return new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                super.remove();
            }

            @Override
            public void set(DateFormat value) {
                super.set(value);
            }

        };

        public void clean() {
            df.remove();
        }

        public Date convertStringToDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
            return df.get().parse(dateString);
        }

    }

}
```