# Java - JAXB problem marshalling Local Date

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

can anyone help me with this. I can't seem to pass in my date records to my XML file using JAXB. Searched through the forums and haven't found anything. I tried them and they didn't work. Checking the list, nothing is null, so there's no problem there. the format isn't changed. I just don't see it in my result .xml file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Personnel class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="List")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Personnel {
       
      @XmlElement
      private List<Personnel> personnel;
      private int id;
      private LocalDate birthDate;
      private LocalDate startDate;
      private String name;
}
```

Result

```
<List>
   <personnel>
     <id>1</id>
     <birthDate>
     <startDate>
     <name>John</name>
   </personnel>
   <personnel>
     <id>2</id>
     <birthDate>
     <startDate>
     <name>Mike</name>
   </personnel>
</List>
```

Comment: This answer can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156741/marshalling-localdate-using-jaxb

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Already tried that but it's still the same. <birthDate/>, <startDate/>.

Comment: @Dimitrii, playing around with the solution finally got it to work. I was annotating my class, instead did it to the  package. Thank you.